# Sql to mysql query convert

Tags: php, mysql

I write a query but its not give right result in php mysql

```
CREATE TABLE score
    (`id` int, `member` varchar(3), `score` int)
;

INSERT INTO score
    (`id`, `member`, `score`)
VALUES
    (1, 'abc', 1),
    (2, 'def', 5 ),
    (3, 'ghi', 100),
    (4, 'jkl', 3)
;

SELECT    @rankNo:=@rankNo+1 RankNo,
          a.*
FROM      score a, (SELECT @rankNo:=0) r 
ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

its work in sql but not work correctly in mysql

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there an error message, or are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: It show id 4 as rank 1 but it will be id 3 is rank 1 @Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running multiple queries at once which you cannot do unless you use functionality that specifically supports it (i.e. `mysqli_multi_query()`) which you almost certainly are not.

You need to run those queries separately for it to work with `mysql_*` functions.